# How to using ffmpeg to insert logo to the live video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have one question: How to using ffmpeg to insert logo to one udp streaming of live video?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overlay video filter in ffmpeg to insert your logo. Since you provided no specifics I can only give you a generic example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay -f mpegts udp://hostname:port
```

See the official FFmpeg documentation on the [overlay video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) and the [UDP protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp) for more details and examples.

Use the most recent version or build of ffmpeg that you can compile or acquire. Since you provided no additional information I can not recommend anything specific other than the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.